# Get JaCoCo Integration Coverage from Sonar

Tags: java, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I am developing an application using sonar [Java web service client API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client). I would like to get Integration Test code coverage per class from the [JaCoCo plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JaCoCo+Plugin). Can this be done with this API?

Comment: The web service API is used to access Sonar's REST API as a client. Otherwise why would your program be any different to another Java program? Use the standard JaCoCo directions for integration with your Maven (or ANT) build.

Comment: I already have the JaCoCo plugin in my Sonar, I want to access JaCoCo's data from the Sonar web service API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mark said, you just have to use the [WS API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API) to query the database. What you're missing is probably the name of the metrics related to integration tests (they are not documented yet on our [metric definitions page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Metric+definitions)). So here they are:

- it_coverage
- it_lines_to_cover
- it_uncovered_lines
- it_line_coverage
- it_coverage_line_hits_data
- it_conditions_to_cover
- it_uncovered_conditions
- it_branch_coverage
- it_conditions_by_line